# Alternative to "FOR JSON" in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, json

In SQL Server 2016 I can output query results as `JSON` as described in the documentation [Format Query Results as JSON with FOR JSON (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server)

```
SELECT * 
FROM x 
FOR JSON PATH
```

But I'm finding that this is not supported in SQL Server 2012.

Is there a built-in way to convert tabular data to `JSON` data in SQL Server 2012?

To make this cross compatible I would ideally like to be able to use `for json path` in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012, you can use `FOR XML`. For my case, this was a viable alternative to `JSON`, since I was just passing the string to a browser.

Answer (score 6):

No. JSON support was new in SQL Server 2016.

If you want to convert data to JSON, you have a few options:

- Fetch the rows as you would any other query result, and convert it in the application tier (like C#, Java, etc)
- Build T-SQL logic in a stored procedure or function to convert it to JSON yourself (but keep in mind that you won't be able to use "FOR JSON PATH" the exact same way 2016 does)
- Build CLR logic to do it (again, won't be compatible with "FOR JSON PATH")

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

You can play with this but change the formatting for your `JSON`. This stores all the results as one item:

```
$server = 'Test'
$mainquery = sqlcmd -E -S $server -Q "set nocount on; select name,database_id,compatibility_level from sys.databases" -m 10 -h-1 
$mainquery | convertto-json #-Depth 3
```

Alternatively, you can build your own functions as described in [Producing JSON Documents from SQL Server queries via TSQL](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/producing-json-documents-from-sql-server-queries-via-tsql/) by Phil Factor.

Answer (score -1):

Working solution to build JSON data out of SQL Server 2012

```
    DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @TempTableColumns TABLE (
        [Object_Id] NVARCHAR(100),
        [TableName] NVARCHAR(100),
        [ColumnName] NVARCHAR(100),
        [ColumnSequence] INT,
        [Type] NVARCHAR(100)
    )

    INSERT INTO @TempTableColumns ([Object_Id],[TableName],[ColumnName],[ColumnSequence],[Type])
    SELECT 
        [T].[OBJECT_ID] [Object_Id]
        , [T].[Name]
        , [C].[Name] [ColumnName]
        , [C].[column_id] AS [ColumnSequence]
        , UPPER(CASE 
            WHEN 
                UPPER([ST].[Name]) = 'VARCHAR' OR UPPER([ST].[Name]) = 'NVARCHAR' THEN [ST].[Name] + '(' +  CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,[C].[Max_Length]) = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,[C].[Max_Length]) END + ')' 
            ELSE [ST].[Name] END) [Type]
        FROM SYS.COLUMNS [C] 
        INNER JOIN SYS.TYPES [ST] ON [C].[System_Type_Id] = [St].[System_Type_Id]
        INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES [T] ON [C].[OBJECT_ID] = [T].[OBJECT_ID] 
        WHERE [ST].[Name] <> 'sysname'
    ORDER BY [T].[Name], [C].[column_id]
    
    SELECT 
        [T1].[TableName], 
        REPLACE('SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + (SELECT T3.ColumnName FROM @TempTableColumns T3 WHERE T3.TableName = T1.TableName AND T3.ColumnSequence = 1) + ' ASC) SequenceNumber, ''{' + 
        STUFF(( 
            SELECT '"' + T2.ColumnName + '": '' + CASE WHEN ' + T2.ColumnName + ' IS NULL THEN ''NULL'' ELSE ''"'' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ' + T2.ColumnName + ') + ''"'' END  + '','
                FROM @TempTableColumns AS T2 WHERE T1.TableName = T2.TableName
                FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1, 0,'')  + '}'' DataResults FROM ['+ T1.TableName +'] WITH (NOLOCK)', ',}','}') AS [Query]
    
    FROM @TempTableColumns [T1]
    WHERE T1.TableName >= @TableName OR @TableName = ''
    GROUP BY [T1].[TableName]
```

The Output of queries would return Select statement as follows :

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) SequenceNumber, '{"ID": ' + CASE WHEN ID IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ID) + '"' END  + ',"DatabaseName": ' + CASE WHEN DatabaseName IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), DatabaseName) + '"' END  + ',"SchemaName": ' + CASE WHEN SchemaName IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), SchemaName) + '"' END  + ',"ObjectName": ' + CASE WHEN ObjectName IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ObjectName) + '"' END  + ',"ObjectType": ' + CASE WHEN ObjectType IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ObjectType) + '"' END  + ',"IndexName": ' + CASE WHEN IndexName IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), IndexName) + '"' END  + ',"IndexType": ' + CASE WHEN IndexType IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), IndexType) + '"' END  + ',"StatisticsName": ' + CASE WHEN StatisticsName IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), StatisticsName) + '"' END  + ',"PartitionNumber": ' + CASE WHEN PartitionNumber IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), PartitionNumber) + '"' END  + ',"ExtendedInfo": ' + CASE WHEN ExtendedInfo IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ExtendedInfo) + '"' END  + ',"Command": ' + CASE WHEN Command IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Command) + '"' END  + ',"CommandType": ' + CASE WHEN CommandType IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), CommandType) + '"' END  + ',"StartTime": ' + CASE WHEN StartTime IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), StartTime) + '"' END  + ',"EndTime": ' + CASE WHEN EndTime IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), EndTime) + '"' END  + ',"ErrorNumber": ' + CASE WHEN ErrorNumber IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ErrorNumber) + '"' END  + ',"ErrorMessage": ' + CASE WHEN ErrorMessage IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ErrorMessage) + '"' END  + '}' DataResults FROM [CommandLog] WITH (NOLOCK)
```

and when you run individual queries returned from above. Would give you the output as follows :

```
{"ID": "79143","DatabaseName": "msdb","SchemaName": NULL,"ObjectName": NULL,"ObjectType": NULL,"IndexName": NULL,"IndexType": NULL,"StatisticsName": NULL,"PartitionNumber": NULL,"ExtendedInfo": NULL,"Command": "DECLARE @ReturnCode int EXECUTE @ReturnCode = dbo.xp_create_subdir N'G:\Backup\AWS19WVSQL072\msdb\FULL' IF @ReturnCode <> 0 RAISERROR('Error creating directory.', 16, 1)","CommandType": "xp_create_subdir","StartTime": "Jul 18 2020  1:00AM","EndTime": "Jul 18 2020  1:00AM","ErrorNumber": "0","ErrorMessage": NULL}

{"ID": "79144","DatabaseName": "msdb","SchemaName": NULL,"ObjectName": NULL,"ObjectType": NULL,"IndexName": NULL,"IndexType": NULL,"StatisticsName": NULL,"PartitionNumber": NULL,"ExtendedInfo": NULL,"Command": "BACKUP DATABASE [msdb] TO DISK = N'G:\Backup\AWS19WVSQL072\msdb\FULL\AWS19WVSQL072_msdb_FULL_20200718_010056.bak' WITH CHECKSUM, NO_COMPRESSION","CommandType": "BACKUP_DATABASE","StartTime": "Jul 18 2020  1:00AM","EndTime": "Jul 18 2020  1:01AM","ErrorNumber": "0","ErrorMessage": NULL}
```

Comment: I think if you included actual JSON output for your query to the answer it would be helpful.

Comment: Sure that would be good to get an idea